# Call a controller method via button in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a button in views/companies/edit.html.haml for `destroy_referrals` method, but I can't get the button to work. To call the action on a button I tried to create a new route, but I am still receiving the error *The action 'destroy_referrals' could not be found for CompaniesController*

I created a `destroy_referrals` method in `Admin::CompaniesController`,

```
def destroy_referrals
    load_company
    @company.destroy_referrals
    flash[:notice] = 'Referrals deleted'
    redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

it manipulates the `company.rb` model to find the referrals from users with the same company_id and destroys them,

```
def destroy_referrals
    Referral.joins(:user).where("users.company_id = ?", self.id).destroy_all
end
```

Some things I've tried below...

routes.rb

```
post '/destroy_referrals' => 'admin/companies#destroy_referrals', :as => 'destroy_referrals'
```

views/companies/edit.html.haml

```
= button_to 'Destroy Referrals', destroy_referral_path

= button_to 'Destroy Referrals', admin_company_destroy_referral_path(@company)
```

Comment: Take a moment to read your question. Ask yourself what the words you're using mean, and whether there might be less ambiguous terms that would be more clear. E.g. “To call the action on a button I tried to create a new route”. You don't “call” an “action”, a “button” is a UI concept and also an HTML tag (neither of which have an explicitly defined “action”). Did you create a new route, or did you just try? How did you anticipate that would change things?

Comment: I can run the method through the console and it executes as expected. I am now trying to extend the functionality to the UI and having a button.

Comment: The error seems to indicate it's not going to the admin/companies controller.  Could you post the rest of your routes file?  Is the request being intercepted by another route?

Comment: @Swards the route needed to be `delete 'companies/:id/destroy_referrals' => 'companies#destroy_referrals', :as => 'destroy_referrals'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. HTML links (not “buttons”) aren't wired up to call “methods” directly.
2. The `button_to` method creates an HTML button, which behaves similarly to a link, but with different visual styles.
3. Ruby has methods, which are a common programing construct.
4. HTML links have an `href` attribute that a browser can follow by making a subsequent HTTP request to.
5. When a browser sends a request to your Rails application, the application uses your routes to determine how to handle that *request*.
6. The conventional way to handle a *request* in Rails is to route it to a controller action.
7. A RESTful request to `/products/1` might, by convention, route to the `show` action on the `ProductsController`.
8. In Rails, an “action” is created by defining a *method* on the controller.
9. RESTful routes reflect the **re**presentational **s**tate **t**ransfer paradigm, involving reading, listing, creating, updating, and deleting records/objects.
10. To delete (or destroy) a record, RESTful convention would be to send a `DELETE` request to the Rails application, which would be routed to the relevant controller's `destroy` action, defined by the `destroy` method.
11. You can create an HTML link that results in a browser sending such a request using the `link_to` helper and specifying `method: :delete` in the parameters.
12. You can define a route instructing Rails to handle such a request using the built in “resourceful” routing: e.g. `resources :products`. Alternately, an explicit route can be defined: `delete '/products/:id' => 'products#destroy'`.

This all said, the error Rails is giving you is that it can't find the `destroy_referrals` method in `CompaniesController`. Defining methods in `Admin::CompaniesController` won't do anything to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks Corey, not the silver bullet I was hoping for but something for me to step back and reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

> @Swards the route needed to be delete
>   'companies/:id/destroy_referrals' => 'companies#destroy_referrals',
>   :as => 'destroy_referrals'

I thought it might be a simple fix.  Do you still need the admin namespace?

Consider this, instead of creating a named route

```
namespace 'admin' do
  resources :companies do
    delete 'destroy_referrals', :on => :member, :as => 'destroy_referrals'
  end
end
```

And refer to it as `admin_destroy_referrals_company_path`

```
= button_to 'Destroy Referrals', admin_destroy_referrals_company_path(@company), :method => :delete
```

Comment: `admin_destroy_referrals_company_path` is a url_helper and only returns a URI; in order to send a `DELETE` request (or a mocked `POST` request using the `_method=delete` parameter) you need to specify the `method: :delete` option and have `rails_ujs.js` on the page as well.

Comment: That's right, method delete is needed on the button_to.